# Flutter : blockprovider.of() called with a contextblockprovider.of() called with a context

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i am gonna ask something
[TheError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvn24.png)

i have a bloc i named it CountBloc and i its for my MainScreen
when i put my Home = MainScreen() there is nothing error , but when i put Home : splashScreen() its gonna be error

i am gonna make like this
SplashScreen > Login > AppScreen
in AppScreen i put bottomNavigationBar
HomeScreen(),NewScreen(), AccountScreen(),MainScreen(),

when i click my MainScreen() its gonna be error

main.dart
https://www.codepile.net/pile/KLWkDNLq

Mainscreen.dart
https://www.codepile.net/pile/z7Y2WVn3

Counter.dart
https://www.codepile.net/pile/og7ekYKe

Comment: Hi. And welcome to StackOverflow. Please insert your error code as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make MaterialApp as child of BlocProvider. Right now, the home is BlocProvider.